# Print between two matches with awk

Tags: awk

I want to rearrange the input with the following line but I keep getting ENDD on the wrong line.

```
awk '/output/ {printf $0":";flag=1;next} /ENDD/{flag=0;} flag {printf  $0 "," ;}{if (flag==0)print}' file
```

Input:

```
exam1
exam4 1
output
list2
frame 3
list 5
ENDD
col 1
cal 2
del 3
```

Output:

```
exam1
exam4 1
output:list2,frame 3,list 5,ENDD
col 1
cal 2
del 3
```

Desired Output:

```
exam1
exam4 1
output:list2,frame 3,list 5
ENDD
col 1
cal 2
del 3
```

Comment: Try `awk '/output/ {printf $0":";flag=1;next} /ENDD/{flag=0;print "";} flag {printf  $0 ",";}{if (flag==0)print}' file`

Comment: This leaves an extra comma after the output: line.This seems like a computer science homework assignment though. Should we be doing someones homework here?

Comment: @slobobaby, this is not a homework, it is just a part of a larger script I'm working on. And if you are not ok with solving someone else's homework, you should just ignore it. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: No, the difference between homework and not homework is downvote or no downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
awk ' /output/ { printf "%s:",$0; flag=1; next } 
      /ENDD/{ print ""; flag=0; } 
      flag>1 { printf ","; }
      flag { printf "%s",$0; flag++ }
      !flag' file
```

you get

```
exam1
exam4 1
output:list2,frame 3,list 5
ENDD
col 1
cal 2
del 3
```

**edit: another solution**

```
awk -v ini=output -v end=ENDD '
  $0 ~ ini, $0 ~ end{
    printf ($0~ini? "%s:" : ($0~end? "\n%s\n" : (prev ~ ini? "%s" : ",%s"))), $0; 
    prev=$0; 
    next;
  } 1' file
```

Comment: it is a good practice to always define format pattern when using `printf`

Comment: @Kent i added format pattern to `printf`, thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/ENDD/   { print rec; inRec=0 }
inRec    { rec = rec sep $0; sep="," }
/output/ { rec=$0 ; sep=":"; inRec=1 }
!inRec

$ awk -f tst.awk file
exam1
exam4 1
output:list2,frame 3,list 5
ENDD
col 1
cal 2
del 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution (than my original):

```
awk '/output/ {printf $0":";flag=1;idx=0;next} /ENDD/{printf last "\n";flag=0} flag {if (last) printf last ","; last=$0}{if (flag==0)print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed '/output/{N;s/\n/:/;:1;N;/ENDD/!{s/\n/,/;b1}}' file
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10861801)

Comment: @LucaDetomi In what way ?

Comment: An answer should contain details about "why" this could be a good solution for question or maybe the best one. You provided code snippet but no details to let users understand why this code will run. I suggest you to provide more details commenting your code.

Comment: @LucaDetomi Better get flagging  99% of the answers on this site for not being an answer then or at least all  the other answers on this question. Also please point me to the rule that answers should contain details about why ?

Comment: Your answer was flagged as "too short" and for this reason included in a specific section of the site that requires moderation by users that read posts and say their opinion. The comment posted by me is an automatic one from that section after flagged your answer best suitable as comment that as answer. Answers are more complete that comments and SO always encourage "details" that et users understand proposed solutions

Comment: @LucaDetomi Cool, delete my answer then, make sure to flag all the others though :)